# How to make it so my cursor is not behind the UI?

Tags: unity, 2d

My cursor keeps going behind the UI how to make it go above?

Comment: If you want help correcting the setup of your UI and cursor, you should **edit your question** to show us how you have set up your UI and cursor. Without this, we're forced to just guess at what you did wrong, leading to potentially unhelpful answers if we guess wrong. 

Comment: My cursor is a custom cursor i made with a script does that effect it?

Comment: You can implement almost anything with a script. What matters is the specifics of what that script does. You should absolutely, 100% of the time, include the scripts required to reproduce your problem when asking a question here.